# (java) set size of a vector

Tags: java, list, vector

I am facing a very simple issue :

```
List<String> myList = new Vector<String>(10);
myList.add(5,"HELLO");
```

gives me `ArrayOutOfBoundException : 5>0`

Is there a way to specify the size of a Vector and fill the list in random order?

Comment: You could use good old arrays for this: `String[] arr = new String[10];
        arr[5] = "HELLO";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not specifying the size, you're specifying the capacity of `Vector`.
You *could* do:

```
List<String> myList = new Vector<String>();
for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    myList.add(null);
myList.set(5, "HELLO");
```

What you **should** do is forget the `Vector` class, since it's been outdated for over 10 years already.

If you just need fixed size and random access, you can use an array

`String[] myArr = new String[10];`

If you need it to be a `Collection`, you can use

`List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(myArr);`

Finally if you want to add more elements in it (`Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed size list) you can use

`List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArr));`

Comment: ArrayList is non-synchronized while Vector is synchronized.
Also we all have some legacy code that is not intended to be refactored in near future :)

Comment: @IgorVuković That's still not a reason to use it. You can use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());` if you really do need a synchronized list. Using `Vector` means that you're not really up to date on Java's classes.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the `add()` method explicitly states:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

Since your size at the moment is 0, the behaviour is as expected.
The constructor of the `Vector` class specifies the initial capacity, not the size of the collection.

After checking out what was said in the comments, I am removing my suggestion. It's better to stick to arrays in that case.

Comment: Switching to `ArrayList` will not solve anything. This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe it's because of the last line. `ArrayList` has the [same limitation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) on size as `Vector` when it comes to add element by index

Comment: Are you going to leave this misleading attempt at an answer here? I'm worried that 2 people actually upvoted your response.

Comment: I removed the wrong part, what is left is accurate IMHO.